# Python: Impossible to import mktime in Eclipse: ImportError

Tags: python, eclipse, import, module, pgdb

If I import pgdb just in command line, it works fine.

It was also working fine in Eclipse until recently (with exactly the same Python 2.7.2), but now, when I import pgdb, even in a very simple file (containing just `import pgdb`), I have this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../src/pgdbtest.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pgdb
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/pgdb.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/_pg.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/_pg.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 908, in resource_filename
    self, resource_name
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1383, in get_resource_filename
    self._extract_resource(manager, self._eager_to_zip(name))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1401, in _extract_resource
    timestamp = time.mktime(date_time)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mktime'
```

In fact, more generally, I discovered that if I try `from time import mktime`, I also have error:

```
from time import mktime
ImportError: cannot import name mktime
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, stupid mistake: I created a package named "time"...

So I just deleted it and everything is alright now.